# State Value is not updated in button click event using React

Tags: reactjs, redux

State value is not updated in once click the button using React JS. I have declared one state variable name is `order`.Then I store some value in order state but i clicked the button order value is not updated.

I want to updated `order` once I click the button the state order is empty array.

```
   onPlaceOrderItem(event) {
    let packageData = this.state.order;
    this.setState({
        order: isEmptyData
    })
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(itemActions.placeOrderItems(packageData))
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Are you expecting empty array or original this.state.order

Comment: what is isEmptyData?

Comment: isEmptyData value is [].

Comment: i want set empty value. ex( this.state.order = [])

Comment: Make sure you are not setting any value for order inside itemActions.placeOrderItems(packageData).

Comment: first order value sending to action then want empty array

Comment: Can you show me full component code ?

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState({ order: isEmptyData })` will not mutate `this.state.order` when called. `this.state.order` will be mutated later.

[State updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). As a result, you should not count on `packageData` (aka `this.state.order`) when dispatching `itemActions.placeOrderItems(packageData)`.

A solution may be give the updated `order` value to `setState` and `placeOrderItems`:

```
onPlaceOrderItem(event) {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;

  const order = isEmptyData;
  this.setState({order})
  dispatch(itemActions.placeOrderItems(order))
}
```

But you cannot assume that both the reducer state and the component state will be updated at the same time.

Anyway, if `order` is mutated in the reducer, `order` value from the reducer should be injected in your component and the component state removed.